# Php echo 3 rows of database with divider

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to echo 3 places in a stored database,  break them with a html divider and then echo a further 3 places followed by a html divider and so on. At the moment the code I have just prints one place followed by the divider. Is there an easy way of doing this?

```
<? 

include_once "connect_to_mysql.php";


$sql = mysql_query("SELECT `p_id`, `pname`, `address`, `country`, `type` FROM places WHERE category='ecodo'");
$count = mysql_num_rows($sql);


while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
$p_id = $row["p_id"];
$pname = $row["pname"];
$address = $row["address"];
$country = $row["country"];
$type = $row["type"];

echo '  


            <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 md-margin-bottom-40">
                <div class="easy-block-v2">
                    <img alt="" src="placeFiles/'.$p_id.'/pic1.jpg">       
                    <h3>'.$pname.'</h3>
                    <ul class="list-unstyled">
                        <li><span class="color-green">Type: </span>'.$type.'</li>
                        <li><span class="color-green">Address: </span>'.$address.'</li>
                        <li><span class="color-green">Country:</span>'.$country.'</li>
                    </ul>    
                    <a class="btn-u btn-u-sm" href="place_profile.php?p_id='.$p_id.'">See More</a>
                </div>  
            </div>
            <!-- Divider -->
                    <div class="clearfix margin-bottom-20"><hr></div>
                <!-- Easy Blocks v2 -->
            <div class="row">';

}
?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple counter variable should work.

```
$counter = 0;
while ($row = ... ) {

    if ( ! $counter++ % 3) {
        echo 'Divider';
    }

    // Rest of code
}
```

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'var' (T_VAR)

Comment: Oh whoops, I've been writing JS all morning ^_^ Just remove the `var` keyword haha

Comment: Sorry, getting that error when I use your code. Thanks for your help by the way!

Comment: No problem! Thanks very much. Still doesn't seem to be working though. I think I'm probably just inserting the code incorrectly (I've come to realise php is not my forte..) This is what I have:

Comment: Hey Joe, I still can't seem to get this to work. I'm new to this whole coding thing. Is there any way you could pop up the code with my code in it? Thanks!

Comment: Looking at your post of the current code, what doesn't work with it? It looks about right, the only thing you'd need to change for that setup is setting `$counter = 1;` to begin with

Comment: I changed $counter = 1; but the it seem to just be echoing the divider and then echoing all the rows as usual without the divider. Do I need to add 1 to the $counter for each time the $row is executed?

Comment: Apologies for my poor grammar, spelling errors and poor lack of knowledge in general. I've been up for a very long time trying to build this website! I really appreciate your help, Joe. :)

Comment: Ah, my bad - the logic isn't quite right. The negation operator ( ! ) takes effect before the modulus ( % ) not afterwards. This fixes it: `! ($counter++ % 3)`